# how to make only one video play at a time using react player

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of react player components with different videos I want to play. Right now they can all play at the one time but I want to be able to make it so that only 1 can play at a time so if one is clicked to play the others are all paused but i am not too sure how to go about that and could do with some help. I have a play state created but I am not too sure what to do with it to achieve the outcome I want.

here is my code:

I have my main component here:

```
  const videos = data.map((item) => {
  return <Playlist url={item.url} id={item.id} />;
});

return (
  <div className="sidebar-container" style={styles.container}>
    <button className="add-playlist" onClick={(props) => addPlaylist()}>
      Add New Playlist
    </button>
    <p>sidebar for now!</p>
    {videos}
  </div>
);
```

Here is the code for my playlist component right now which is what the videos array is made up of:

```
const [play, setPlay] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="playlist-container">
      
        <ReactPlayer url={props.url} id={props.id} playing={play} />
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Does anyone know what i can do to achieve my desired outcome?

Answer (score 2):

How about using a unique ID to determine which state the "play" button applies to? Something like this:

```
const [play, setPlay] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="playlist-container">
      
        <ReactPlayer url={props.url} id={props.id} playing={play === props.id} />
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

where the corresponding "Play" button has an onClick function to `setPlay(playerId)`?

Comment: with the react player i don't have a button to trigger the play you just click on the youtube video and it plays so i was wondering how to make it so that when one is clicked all of the other stop playing from. Maybe i am misunderstanding your answer can you go into a bit more detail about how this would work?

Comment: @Jimbhoy How do you change the state of `play`? How are you going to detect that a youtube video was clicked inside your `ReactPlayer`?

Comment: i do not have anything like that implemented although the youtube videos play when you click on the video like if you where on youtube like normal. Are you suggesting that I have a button to change the state of each of the ReactPlayers

Comment: but what you are suggesting to have a button to detect that a youtube video was clicked if this was implemented how would it stop the other videos from not playing when one is clicked

Comment: Because `playing={play === props.id}` will evaluate to `playing={false}` for all but one ID.

Comment: ok i understand what you are meaning now do you think it would be worth adding a button to each of my react player components inside my videos array?

Comment: @Jimbhoy If the `ReactPlayer` component can control the state of the video, then yes.